# Inline code in spoilers is broken

Tags: bug, status-completed, design

If you use markdown of the form

```
>! `a`
```

you get bad results nowadays.

On main:
[image]

On meta:
[image]

The text is almost unreadable due to very dark background.

Comment: Can not reproduce with new beta theme and FF 62.